# How to run my MATLAB code independently on Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-4, matlab

I have a MATLAB code,the aim is to get the output through the input.And I want to run it independently in raspberry pi.My input and output are obtained in simulink.I just want to know how to make this code run independently in Raspberry Pi.Here is my code:

```
function tablelook()%#codegen
g = 41;
optimal = [];
for i = 1:g
    all = coder.load('soldata.mat');
    data = struct2cell(all);
    H = data{1}{i}.H;
    K = data{1}{i}.K;
    Fi = data{1}{i}.Fi;
    Gi = data{1}{i}.Gi;
    if H*[Troom;tout] <= K
        optimal(i) = Fi * [Troom;tout] + Gi;
    else
        optimal(i) = 1;
    end
end
S_pre = min(optimal);
out = S_pre;
write(pc,out,'int8')
end
```

Can you give me some advices or paper about it?
Many thanks,
Bang

Comment: [Read this](https://www.mathworks.com/hardware-support/raspberry-pi-matlab.html)